# Does TIGER/Line road dataset contain one-way/two-way traffic information?

Tags: gis, arcgis, tiger-lines

I am working on a routing project, and I need to populate the road network with the type of roads and one-way/two-way traffic information. I wonder if the TIGER/Line road dataset contains such data.

I downloaded a TIGER/Line road dataset for the state of California, but there was no such information.